# How should DJ Fenris be played?

Tags: android-netrunner

I can't catch how [DJ Fenris](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/22025) should be played in terms of the game rules? I just bring [all 13 g-mod ids](https://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=s%3AG-mod), put them somewhere on the table and choose one of them when the Fenris is installed? Or this ids should be part of the deck?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have ID cards **in** your deck;
so any ID hosted on [DJ Fenris](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/22025) is **not** part of your deck, it's similar to [Rebirth](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/10083) in that regard.

You don't have to bring all eligible IDs, only ones you ever plan to use.
You also don't have to show which additional IDs you have to your opponent until you actually play Rebirth or DJ.

You are still limited by the IDs legal in the format you're playing, 
so for Standard; Noise and other rotated runners as well as draft IDs are out.
Your faction will limit choices too.